# document.getElementById shows either pictures or text

Tags: javascript

i made a popup with this code

```
document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML='
        <img class="popuppic" src="gfx/k'+clicks[0].imageNum+'.jpg">
        <img class="headline" src="gfx/k'+clicks[0].imageNum+'.jpg"> 
        <p>'+textarr[clicks[0].imageNum]+'</p>
        <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'popup\').style.display=\'none\'">';
```

so the popup shows me a div including 2 pictures, one text and one close button. My problem is that it shows me either 2 pics + the close button or just the text. when i delete tis part`<p>'+textarr[clicks[0].imageNum]+'</p>`it only shows me the pictures with the button. when i include this part it only shows me the text without anything else. no pictures, no button.

where is the fault?

Comment: Please edit your code block to be more readable

Comment: What is in `textarr[clicks[0].imageNum]`?

Comment: I hope you realize that you can't spread a javascript string out over multiple lines like you have in your question.  You would have to quote each piece and add them together.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP edited from one long string.

Comment: @epascarello - and now they're showing illegal javascript.

Comment: what is textarr and what is clicks?